# How to include lambda calculus code in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, code

What is the best way to include lambda calculus code in LaTeX (like in Courier new font), especially one that allows for the use of math symbols as well like $\lambda$ throughout the environment.

For example, I'm trying to typeset:

```
fix fib : int $\rightarrow$ int . 

$\lambda$ n : int .

if (n < 2) then n

else (fib (n-1)) (fib (n-2))
```

Comment: What style are you trying to get? Usually the λcalculus is a quite theoretical tool so it is rendered as math formulas. If you are using it as a programming language maybe you have a specific syntactic variant in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?
It uses the [`listings`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf) package to "parse" the input and print it with the appropriate styling. Check the manual to see all the options. The package allows very advanced customisation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{Lambda}{%
  morekeywords={%
    if,then,else,fix % keywords go here
  },%
  morekeywords={[2]int},   % types go here
  otherkeywords={:}, % operators go here
  literate={% replace strings with symbols
    {->}{{$\to$}}{2}
    {lambda}{{$\lambda$}}{1}
  },
  basicstyle={\sffamily},
  keywordstyle={\bfseries},
  keywordstyle={[2]\itshape}, % style for types
  keepspaces,
  mathescape % optional
}[keywords,comments,strings]%

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Lambda]
fix fib : int -> int.
  lambda n : int.
    if (n < 2) then n$^2$
    else (fib (n-1)) (fib (n-2))
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

With output:

[image: output]

If you prefer the typewriter font just change `\sffamily` to `\ttfamily` but be advised that not all the typewriter fonts support bold (Computer Modern doesn't).

With the option `mathescape` you can put math inside `$` and get it rendered within your λcalculus code.
The styling I choose here is just for demonstration.
If you need a bold lambda, you can include `amsmath` and use `\boldsymbol\lambda` instead of just `\lambda`.